# How can I notify users with Firebase method when URL link updates whic I take data with parse method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

(React Native)I have a code block which has url link and take product details with parse method but when link updates I want to notify users automaticly with firebase method.I can send push notification with manual after took token but like I said before how can I do it automaticly when url link updates. Please help I need your knowledge!!!

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

const App = () => {
  const [recalledProducts, setRecalledProducts] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecalledProducts();
  }, [currentPage]);

  const fetchRecalledProducts = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://www.gov.uk/product-safety-alerts-reports-recalls?page=${currentPage}`);
      const html = await response.text();
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      const products = [];

      $('.gem-c-document-list__item').each((index, element) => {
        const title = $(element).find('.gem-c-document-list__item-title').text().trim();
        const summary = $(element).find('.gem-c-document-list__item-description').text().trim();
        const date = $(element).find('.gem-c-document-list__item-metadata').text().trim();

        products.push({ title, summary, date });
      });

      setRecalledProducts(products);
      setIsLoading(false);

      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Hata:', error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  };

  const handlePrevPage = () => {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        onScroll={(event) => {
          const { y } = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
          scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, y, animated: true });
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>PRODUCT RECALLS</Text>
        </View>
        {isLoading ? (
          <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#666666" />
            <Text style={styles.loadingText}>Loading</Text>
          </View>
        ) : (
          recalledProducts.map((product, index) => (
            <View key={index}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{product.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.summary}>{product.summary}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.date}>{product.date}</Text>
              {index < recalledProducts.length - 1 && <View style={styles.divider} />}
            </View>
          ))
        )}
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
        <View style={styles.pageBox}>
          <Text style={styles.pageText}>Page: {currentPage}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      {currentPage > 1 && (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.backButton} onPress={handlePrevPage}>
          <Text style={styles.backButtonText}>Back</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.nextButton} onPress={handleNextPage}>
        <Text style={styles.nextButtonText}>Next</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#d9d9d9',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: '10%',
  },
  headerContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#bfbfbf',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#333333',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 2,
    color: '#333333',
  },
  summary: {
    fontSize: 12,
    marginBottom: 0,
    color: '#555555',
    lineHeight: 16,
    textAlign: 'justify',
  },
  date: {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    color: '#888888',
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
  nextButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    right: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#666666',
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  nextButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  backButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#666666',
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  backButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  divider: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  pageContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    paddingBottom: 20,
  },
  pageBox: {
    backgroundColor: '#bfbfbf',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  pageText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  loadingContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  loadingText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 10,
    color: '#666666',
  },
});
```

export default App;